# Why getDayOfWeek does not return day number of week?

Tags: java, dayofweek

I have written code to print the day number of week, from 1 - Monday ...

I found this:

```
java.time.DayOfWeek num = LocalDate.of(year, month, day).getDayOfWeek();
System.out.println(num);
```

Example output:

```
> FRIDAY
```

So, instead of printing the *number*, it prints the *name* of the day.

How can I fix it?

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is.

Comment: *First day of week* varies by culture. For example, in the United States, Sunday is usually considered first day of the week, not Monday as you suggest in your Question. See [`WeekFields#getFirstDayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html#getFirstDayOfWeek()).

Comment: If this is for printing only and you want to take the first day of the week according to the default locale into account, you may use `LocalDate.of(year, month, day).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("e", Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.DISPLAY)))`.

Comment: To answer the question in your title: It’s very sensible to have an `enum` like `DayOfWeek` for the days of the ISO week (Monday though Sunday). For most applications this makes a lot more sense than using numbers. On the other hand meaning that when for once you do need the number, you have just a little more work to do.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.getValue()` to obtain the day number:

```
int dayNumberOfWeek = LocalDate.of(2022, 10, 02).getDayOfWeek().getValue();
```

The [Java docs for DayOfWeek](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) says:

> public int getValue()
>
> Gets the day-of-week int value.
>
> The values are numbered following the ISO-8601 standard, from 1 (Monday) to 7 (Sunday). See WeekFields.dayOfWeek() for localized week-numbering.

Comment: This answer is very well formatted and illustrates the docs by example. To encourage _do-your-own-research before asking_, a comment pointing to the docs would have sufficed: [`int num = anyLocalDate.getDayOfWeek().getValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#getValue())